# Does the function monad really offer something more than the function applicative functor? If so, what?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, applicative, combinatory-logic

For the function monad I find that `(<*>)` and `(>>=)`/`(=<<)` have two strikingly similar types. In particular, `(=<<)` makes the similarity more apparent:

```hs
(<*>) :: (r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
(=<<) :: (a -> r -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
```

So it's like both `(<*>)` and `(>>=)`/`(=<<)` take a binary function and a unary function, and [constrain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_(mathematics)) one of the two arguments of the former to be determined from the other one, via the latter. After all, we know that for the function applicative/monad,

```hs
f <*> g = \x -> f x (g x)
f =<< g = \x -> f (g x) x
```

And they look so strikingly similar (or symmetric, if you want), that I can't help but think of the question in the title.

As regards monads being "more powerful" than applicative functors, in the hardcopy of [LYAH's *For a Few Monads More* chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more), the following is stated:

> […] `join` cannot be implemented by just using the functions that functors and applicatives provide.

i.e. `join` can't be implemented in terms of `(<*>)`, `pure`, and `fmap`.

But what about the *function* applicative/mondad I mentioned above?

I know that `join === (>>= id)`, and that for the function monad that boils down to `\f x -> f x x`, i.e. a binary function is made unary by feeding the one argument of the latter as both arguments of the former.

Can I express it in terms of `(<*>)`? Well, actually I think I can: isn't `flip ($) <*> f === join f` correct? Isn't `flip ($) <*> f` an implementation of `join` which does without `(>>=)`/`(=<<)` and `return`?

However, thinking about the list applicative/monad, I can express `join` without explicitly using `(=<<)`/`(>>=)` and `return` (and not even `(<*>)`, fwiw): `join = concat`; so probably also the implementation `join f = flip ($) <*> f` is kind of a trick that doesn't really show if I'm relying just on `Applicative` or also on `Monad`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233507/discussion-on-question-by-enlico-does-the-function-monad-really-offer-something).

Answer (score 21):

When you implement `join` like that, you're using knowledge of the function type beyond what `Applicative` gives you. This knowledge is encoded in the use of `($)`. That's the "application" operator, which is the core of what a function even is. Same thing happens with your list example: you're using `concat`, which is based on knowledge of the nature of lists.

In general, if you can use the knowledge of a particular monad, you can express computations of any power. For example, with `Maybe` you can just match on its constructors and express anything that way. When LYAH says that monad is more powerful than applicative, it means "as abstractions", not applied to any particular monad.

Comment: Fyodor, where would you say the knowledge of the function type is encoded in Will Ness' answer?

Comment: @Enlico `id` is a function. `(<*> id)` is not a polymorphic function that can be used with any applicative. Similarly, only for functions `(>>= id)` and `(id >>=)` are the same.

Comment: @Bergi `id` here is akin to lists' `[]`, not `concat`. that it works is precisely what it means that for functions app. and mon. have same power. otherwise, what are we saying, that in general Monad has more power than App? of course it has, but that wasn't the question. if you could express `join` for lists with `<*>` and `[]`, I'd say it'd mean they have the same power there as well.

Comment: "In general, if you can use the knowledge of a particular monad" you mean "a particular data type". like you suggest using pattern matching. there's no pattern matching on Monad as Monad, only on a data type. as Monad, it knows only `>>=` and `return`.

Comment: That's how it's usually said. You can say "the maybe monad" or "the list monad" or "the state monad".

Comment: yes it is, and that is unfortunate. :) I mean, when we say "the maybe monad" we have in mind the particulars of how Maybe implements Monad, and that is fine. but here, in this context, it is confusing.

Comment: @WillNess I didn't mean to compare `id` to `concat`

Comment: Unaccepted for now as I'm still not sure. On one hand, this answer perfectly tells why I can make without `>>=`, `<*>`, or any other abstraction from the moment I know what the actual data type is. But on the other hand, it doesn't explicitly answer the question in the title. Besides, I start to see Will Ness' point and want some time to think more about it.

Comment: @Enlico I just repeated in my answer what I thought was a long accepted uncontroversial part of Haskell lore. I even think I saw it stated here on SO somewhere.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin just so I can understand, is your answer saying that functions Monad _is_ more powerful than Applicative?

Comment: @WillNess He's saying that the *particular* monad, functions, has the whole power of functions. And so does this particular applicative.

Comment: @Bergi I see what's going on now. by "functions" you mean "any pointful definition I can write in Haskell" and I indeed meant combinators, without realizing it. my argument boils down to `W = CSI`, where `S` is unavoidable. (or there are probably ways to express `S` with `W`). in any case it's SK that's the basis.

Comment: ( Wfx=CSIfx=SfIx=fx(Ix)=fxx. ) using pointful notation reveals nothing illuminating. lambda calculus _is_ turing complete (or something). using combinatory notation reveals additional structure. (and, yes, [`S = B(BW)(BBC)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B,_C,_K,_W_system))

Answer (score 1):

*edit2:* The problem with the question is that it is vague. It uses a notion ("more powerful") that is not defined at all and leaves the reader guessing as to its meaning. Thus we can only get  meaningless answers. Of course anything can be coded while using all arsenal of Haskell at our disposal. This is a vacuous statement. And it wasn't the question.

The cleared-up question, as far as I can see, is: using the methods from Monad / Applicative / Functor respectively as *primitives*, without using explicit pattern matching at all, is the class of computations that can be thus expressed strictly larger for one or the other set of primitives in use. Now *this* can be meaningfully answered.

Functions are opaque though. No pattern matching is present anyway. Without restricting what we can use, again there's no meaning to the question. The restriction then becomes, the explicit use of named arguments, the pointful style of programming, so that we only allow ourselves to code in combinatory style.

So then, for lists, with `fmap` and `app` (`<*>`) only, there's so much computations we can express, and adding `join` to our arsenal does make that larger. Not so with functions. `join = W = CSI = flip app id`. The end.

Having implemented `app f g x = (f x) (g x) = id (f x) (g x) :: (->) r (a->b) -> (->) r a -> (->) r b`, I already have `flip app id :: (->) r (r->b) -> (->) r b`, I might as well call it `join` since the type fits. It already exists whether I wrote it or not. On the other hand, from `app fs xs :: [] (a->b) -> [] a -> [] b`, I can't seem to get `[] ([] b) -> [] b`. Both `->`s in `(->) r (a->b)` are the *same*; functions *are* [special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_object).

(BTW, I don't see at the moment how to *code* the lists' `app` *explicitly* without actually coding up `join` as well. Using list comprehensions is equivalent to using `concat`; and `concat` is *not* implementation of `join`, it *is* `join`).

---

```
join f = f <*> id
```

is simple enough so there's no doubts.

---

(*edit:* well, apparently there were still doubts).

`(=<<) = (<*>) . flip` for functions. that's it. that's what it means that for functions Monad and Applicative Functor are the same. `flip` is a generally applicable combinator. `concat` isn't. There's a certain conflation there, with functions, sure. But there's no specific functions-manipulating function there (like `concat` is a specific lists-manipulating function), or anywhere, because functions are opaque.

Seen as a particular data type, it can be subjected to pattern matching. As a Monad though it only knows about `>>=` and `return`. `concat` does use pattern matching to do its work. `id` does not.

`id` here is akin to lists' `[]`, not `concat`. That it works is precisely what it means that functions seen as Applicative Functor or Monad are the same. Of course in general Monad has more power than Applicative, but that wasn't the question. If you could express `join` for lists with `<*>` and `[]`, I'd say it'd mean they have the same power for lists as well.

In `(=<<) = (<*>) . flip`, both `flip` and `(.)` do nothing *to* the functions they get applied to. So they have no knowledge of those functions' internals. Like, `foo = foldr (\x acc -> x+1) 0` will happen to correctly calculate the length of the argument list if that list were e.g. `[1,2]`. Saying *this*, building on *this*, *is* using some internal knowledge of the function `foo` (same as `concat` using internal knowledge of its argument lists, through pattern matching). But just using basic combinators like `flip` and `(.)` etc., isn't.

Comment: I start to see your point, Will. I've also added the combinatory-logic tag, as it's mostly relevant based on your answer.

Comment: I don't understand. Both `id` and `flip` are specific to functions, and not part of the `Applicative` interface. (Well, `id` actually works for general `Category`s, but it's still not part of `Applicative`.)

Comment: @dfeuer I think the heart of Will's answer is "_id here is akin to lists' [], not concat_", that is if you can combine `<*>` with `[]` to get `join`, than you would have an equivalent proof that applicative and monad are the same for the list instances.

Comment: @dfeuer for functions, `join = (id =<<) = (<*> id)`. if `id` is allowed 
on the left, why shouldn't it be allowed on the right? 
sure it only works for functions, but that just means
that for functions, it works. the true power of monad vs applicative with functions is argument replication (`join f x = f x x`) (and app already has it, `app f g x = (f x) (g x)`, so `join f x = app f id x`... (I didn't think treating `id` as a primitive would be controversial)). the true power of monad vs applicative for lists is nested pattern matching (`join ((x:xs):ys) = x : join (xs:ys)`).

Comment: ... and apparently we can't use `app` as a primitive, to achieve _that_.

Comment: (by "can't" I meant unable to achieve that using just app as a primitive) @dfeuer

Comment: @dfeuer could you help me out please, do you read Fyodor's answer as saying that functions monad is more powerful than applicative? do _you_ think that it is?

Comment: @WillNess As you already mentioned (if I understand you correctly) functions have a dual role: Considered as a data type they form a monad. But they are also the means to encode the monad operations for all instances. However, as I see it now one cannot deduce from this duality that the function type per se is special. `flip` may be more polymorphic than `concat` but it still uses knowledge of the function arrow `->`. `concat` uses pattern matching as the elemination rule of `[]`. But `flip` uses function application as the elimination rule of `->`. Does this make any sense?

Comment: @IvenMarquardt `concat` deconstructs its argument by pattern matching. `flip` does no such thing. there is no data constructor `->` to do the elimination of. having implemented `app f g x = (f x) (g x) = id (f x) (g x) :: (->) r (a->b) -> (->) r a -> (->) r b`, I already have `flip app id :: (->) r (r->b) -> (->) r b`, I might as well call it `join` since the type fits. It already exists whether I wrote it or not. OTOH, from `app fs xs :: [] (a->b) -> [] a -> [] b`, I can't seem to get `[] ([] b) -> [] b`. both `->`s in `(->) r (a->b)` are the same; functions _are_ special. that's all I know.

Comment: @IvenMarquardt (I haven't said nothing new, mind you. see also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67779824/does-the-function-monad-really-offer-something-more-than-the-function-applicativ/67780815#comment119876611_67780815)  here).

Comment: @WillNess So adding `join` doesn't make a difference for the function type and that makes functions special. I still don't understand the combinatory logic part but that is on me. I wish there was a broader debate on this issue, but there isn't and it's probably too much to ask.

Comment: @dfeuer if I may address you here one more time, I really don't understand the objection(s). the Applicative interface is all of two functions; if we could cook up a `join` from the two of them, and only the two of them, that would prove Monad = Applicative _in general_. why would that be even considered? otherwise, I've edited my answer with more stuff (and left more comments around here trying to clarify what I meant), I don't know if you saw it; perhaps it addresses some of the concerns? I must say I'm baffled by this whole thing here.

Comment: @WillNess, the claim is really true for `Proxy`. `Proxy >>= f = Proxy = Proxy <*> Proxy`. It also seems likely true in some categorical sense for `Identity`, thanks to its `pure` being an isomorphism. `x >>= f = f (runIdentity x) = runIdentity (f <$> x)`. For functions, I just don't see the claim being meaningful.

Comment: @dfeuer well I finally googled it, and got e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797418/what-can-the-reader-monad-do-that-applicative-functions-cannot#comment98264475_55797418) (and a supportive comment from luqui few lines down).

Comment: Ah, now I might see. `flip` here is seen as `curry . (. swap) . uncurry`?

Comment: @dfeuer for me, `flip` is **C**. it's primitive. but yes, I guess.

Comment: @dfeuer or maybe you were stressing the fact that **Hask** is CCC and functions are both its morphisms and exponentials. (the problem with me saying this is that I personally barely understand the words I'm using there, that's why I didn't say it in the answer)